# Navbar width, position fixed but not sticky

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with changing the width of my `navbar`. I want the `navbar` to stretch across the screen with a small gap on each end. I have used **`position: fixed`** and  **`width: xx%`** in my CSS to achieve this. However I would like to know if it's possible to make the navbar non-sticky, as in it stays at the top of the page when I scroll. I have tried searching online but to no avail.

I'm using a W3 example to illustrate my issue.

I have feeling this may be just bad practice, in terms of manipulating the `navbar` too much?

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bg-img {
  background-image: url("http://panoramicireland.com/images/2016/03/15/panoramic-ireland-dublin-3513.jpg");
  min-height: 380px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px;
  width: auto;
}

.topnav {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 93%
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<h2>Navbar on Image</h2>
<div class="bg-img">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<div class="line"></div>

<h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<div class="line"></div>

<h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<div class="line"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to just change:

```
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 93vw;
}
```

See it on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Ced___/pen/NEpEzb)

Is it what you were looking for ?

Comment: That's it, appreciate your help

Comment: You're welcome ! :) For more informations vw is Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport see [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) for more details

Comment: @bano590 please remember to upvote the answer (not the comment) if it helped you, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, if I understand correctly you don't want your navbar to be sticky. In this case you don't need position: fixed attribute. I suggest you read and understand the CSS *position* property as it is very important to understand positioning of the elements in the webpage in order to be able to manipulate the page easily. You can start off by reading this from wschools: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Furthermore, I think you're right that you manipulate the navbar too much. Your navbar class is inside a container which does not serve a real purpose in your context, it's redundant. There are multiple ways to solve this problem, but the one I chose is to remove the *container* class and make the following changes to the *topnav* class:

```
.topnav {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 93%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Relative positioning will put your navbar on the top of your page and *margin: 0 auto* will make sure the element is centered.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The **container** is used just to position the navbar away from the top of the page. If I remove it in my example above the navbar rests back at the top of the page

Comment: I think a better approach would be to give topnav some margin-top to separate it from the top of the page.